# Speed up formula building in Z3Py

Tags: python, performance, profiling, z3, sat

I use Z3Py to build large formulas (~1500 `Bool` variables, ~90k assertions) and I am currently using `Solver.add` to add the assertions, which are mostly small (eg. implications on 2 variables).

My code looks something like this, with about 10 outer `for` loops in sequence. The loop nesting depth varies from 2 to 6.

```
s = Solver()

for i in range(A):
  for j in range(B):
    ...
      s.add(Implies(vars[i,j,...], vars[k,l,...]))
```

The problem is that building the solver takes ~11 seconds (with `__debug__ == False`), while finding a solution only takes about 8.

Profiling shows that a lot of time is spent in `Z3_sort_to_ast`, `z3code.Elementaries.Check` (called by the former), and other methods which seem like they could be inlined at least, if not somehow eliminated.

How does one optimize the creation of the Z3 `Solver`? Maybe there is a more low-level, internal interface which could speed things up?

Comment: The Python API is not optimized for speed, it's quite possible that it wastes a bunch of time in unnecessarily deeply nested functions and in assertion/exception/type checks. For peak performance during construction, it's probably best to use the C API directly.

Answer (score 3):

I see 3 options:

- Use the SMT-LIB interface
- Skip the high-level API of Z3
- Rewrite the code using the C API directly

If the interaction with Z3 is minimal (solve and get a model), SMT-LIB might be the best option.

If the python code is quite complex to rewrite in C, please give pySMT a try. The way we integrate with Z3 skips the high-level API, and calls directly the underlying C-functions exposed at the python level. There would be the overhead from pySMT itself, but typically it pays out. You can have a look at [1] for some ideas on how we do it.

[1] https://github.com/pysmt/pysmt/blob/master/pysmt/solvers/z3.py#L853